# Modern List or Library with Choice Field Concurrancy Bug

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

I'm dealing with an issue where two or more people are not able to work in a **modern** list at the same time. The SPO list that I'm working with has a few text fields, one choice field, one date field, and is filled with a few hundred rows.

If a user is editing an item (ID=111) and another user goes into the list and updates and saves a different item (ID=222), the fist user has their choice field selection reset to the default value.

*Steps to reproduce*
Create new Team Site
Create a list (modern exp.)
Add a **choice column**
Add some choices
Add several items to the list

Open two browser sessions
              Browser 1:  edit a list item using the quick launch panel and select a choice value (don’t save)
              Browser 2:  edit a **different item**, select a choice value and save your changes

Result (*wait ~30 seconds*)
Browser 1: selected choice value is reset before the user has a chance to save

Is there anything that can be done to fix this or is reverting to classic SharePoint or creating a PowerApp the only option?

Comment: What does "selected choice value is reset before the user has a chance to save" mean? Which browser you are using? Modern library or classic library? Quick edit or edit form?

Comment: @EmilyDu-MSFT   1) It's outlined in the scenario above.  2) Edge, FF, Chrome  3) Both modern list and library experience 4) Quick edit panel and edit form in the modern experience.

Comment: Have you opened a support case in the M365 admin center? If this is an issue with the service, there isn't much we'll be able to do to help you with your question.

Comment: I dont think this is a concurrancy issue. It sounds like a rerender of the page. This is quite common in the modern experience.